# Having multiple searches in one elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm trying to have a query perform multiple actions in one query. I'm pretty new to Elasticsearch, and I'm unsure if this is possible. This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm trying to do a cardinality aggregation on a field for the time period of 24 hours ago to now, and also do another cardinality aggregation for the time period of 48 hours ago to 24 hours ago.

Is it possible to do both of these in one query?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for `Multi Search API`? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

Comment: Thank you that helps. Also, if ti was trying to search for 48 hours ago to 24 hours ago, how would that look as a search?